# Two workflow rules with different formulas firing for one scenario

Tags: formula, workflow, formula-field, time-dependent-workflow, workflowrule

I have two workflow email alerts when a case is created from an email (email-to-case).

Workflow rule 1:

```
CONTAINS("qa.cancelholidays@gmail.com", Source:EmailMessage.ToAddress)
```

Workflow rule 2:

```
CONTAINS("qa.supportholidays@gmail.com", Source:EmailMessage.ToAddress)
```

Example:
When a user sends an email to "qa.cancelholidays@gmail.com" , a case will be created with email where toAddress is "qa.cancelholidays@gmail.com".
After that the *Workflow rule 1* should fire to send a response.
But currently both Workflow rules are firing

Example:
When a user sends an email to "qa.supportholidays@gmail.com" , a case will be created with email where toAddress is "qa.supportholidays@gmail.com".
After that the *Workflow rule 2* should fire to send a response.
But currently both Workflow rules are firing

Why both rules are firing?

Update: When I debug, the ToAddress Value comes as Null even though the email is there in the case.

Comment: check your debug log; most likely you have recursive updates on the Case. You should also consider switching to Flow as you get more control

Answer (score 0):

You have reversed the parameters in the `CONTAINS()` function, see [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5):

> CONTAINS(text, compare_text) and replace (e.g. compare) text with the text that
> contains the value of compare_text.

So your formula should be

```
CONTAINS(Source:EmailMessage.ToAddress, "qa.cancelholidays@gmail.com")
```

Comment: I tried this way, in that case both are not firing

Comment: How did you get `Source:EmailMessage.ToAddress`  That is not a typical API name for a field.

Comment: this is a formula field reference for ToAddress from EmailMessage object.
Anyway I found the issue.
When workflow rule fires the email is getting created after some seconds, so when I tried to retrive the ToAddress when case created it comes as Null which satisfies both Rules.
Fixed by switching to lightning to fire the triggered Flow by sceduling a delay